# How to create a keyboard shortcut from GUI?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys

Tried to edit the **shortcut** of "Windows key [or Super] + m" from "Launch Mail Reader" to "**Open Mousepad**", since Super + e no longer launches Mousepad in Xubuntu 22.04. But it didn't work. So I tried all kinds of key combinations: Windows/Alt/Ctrl/Fn with F-keys and other keys. No success either. Dell Latitude e6530

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you ask this here already? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432159/cant-type-m-anywhere

Comment: I asked part of it as part of another question ("m" key not responding), which I've since resolved. I think I was cheating by asking 2 questions in 1 post, so thought I'd clean up my act.